# 15 minute interval dependant combo boxes

Tags: javascript

I have a script that uses dependent combo boxes for times.

Currently, the script has 1 hour intervals but it now needs to be 30 minute intervals. I don't know how to add this to this script. How do I alter the script to achieve what I need?

```
for (var hour = 09; hour <= 21; hour++) {
    var startOption = "<option value='"+hour+"'>"+hour+".00</option>";
    $('[name="startTime"]').append(startOption);
}
```

The original script is here: [dependant combo boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790941/dependant-combo-boxes/44791108#44791108).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some like this (pay attention than value of the option is changed):

```
for (var hour = 09; hour <= 21; hour++) { 
     var startOption00= "<option value='"+hour+":00'>"+hour+":00</option>";
     $('[name="startTime"]').append(startOption00);
     var startOption30= "<option value='"+hour+":30'>"+hour+":30</option>";
     $('[name="startTime"]').append(startOption30);
}
```